# Meta API OAUTH exception(#10) while using post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a problem when using meta API I'm trying to post on instagram from javascript, when I'm trying to get access_token, facebook_pages, instagram_business_account_id there's no problem but each time I'm trying to use method post I can't access API :

Request : [https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/${instagram_business_account_id}/media?access_token=${access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/$%7Binstagram_business_account_id%7D/media?access_token=$%7Baccess_token%7D)

Error :

[image]

My application have no type, Facebook Login, Instagram Graph Api and when I was looking on all help topics I had all the permissions needed

If you need the code I can add it if necessary

Comment: This endpoint generally use instagram_basic, pages_show_list and business_management. What is your scopes to call the API?